# PLS-00306 on Oracle function using a UDT

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I am getting this error:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
13/3     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
13/13    PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'JOIN_JT'
```

Types used:

```
CREATE TYPE join_t IS OBJECT (
   inn      NUMBER(38),
   out      NUMBER(38)
);
/

CREATE TYPE join_jt IS TABLE OF join_t;
/
```

Here is the PL/SQL code from the function that is returning the error. When I try to pass the results I have got in `join_table` to `retval` the type error above is triggered):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION join RETURN join_jt
AS
    CURSOR cur_fv_table IS SELECT id,fv FROM london WHERE id <= 3000;

    retval join_jt := join_jt ();
    var_fv london.fv%type;
    var_id london.id%type;
    join_table join_jt := join_jt();
BEGIN
    OPEN cur_fv_table;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur_fv_table INTO var_id,var_fv;

        SELECT join_t(r.id, var_id) BULK COLLECT INTO join_table
        FROM   london r
        WHERE  manh_dist(r.fv,var_fv) <= 5;

        retval.EXTEND;
        retval := join_t(join_table);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN join_table;            
END;
/
```

You can use this function for testing the function above:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION manh_dist(
    fv1 LONDON.FV%TYPE,
    fv2 LONDON.FV%TYPE
) RETURN NUMBER
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 0;                              -- Implement this.
END;
/
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

I am using the Oracle 11g.

Comment: A test harness without any test data is not much use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is your problem:

```
       retval := join_t (join_table);
```

You're trying to cast a table to an object type. Which is wrong. To populate the output table you need to union the query collection with the return collection. MULTISET UNION is what you need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION knn_join RETURN join_jt
IS
CURSOR cur_fv_table IS SELECT id,fv FROM londonfv WHERE id <= 3000;
retval join_jt := join_jt ();
var_fv londonfv.fv%type;
var_id londonfv.id%type;
join_table join_jt := join_jt();
BEGIN
    OPEN cur_fv_table;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur_fv_table INTO var_id,var_fv;
        SELECT join_t(r.id, var_id) BULK COLLECT 
        INTO join_table FROM londonfv r WHERE manhattan_dist(r.fv,var_fv) <=5;
       retval := retval multiset union all join_table;
    END LOOP;   
    RETURN retval;          
END;
/
```

Note: I assume you really meant to return the aggregated collection `retval` rather than the last intermediate set.

---

Not having time to test this right now, I admit @Wernfried has given me some doubt as to whether this will run. If you run into problems, this blunter approach will work:

```
for idx in join_table.first()..join_table.last()
       loop
            Retval.extend();
           retval(retval.count()) := join_table(idx);
       end loop;
```

Comment: In order to use `MULTISET UNION` the nested table must be comparable, see [MULTISET UNION](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/operators006.htm#SQLRF51170). This is not the case for `OBJECT (inn NUMBER, OUT NUMBER)` - unless you define a MAP MEMBER FUNCTION, see [Object Comparison](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/obj_types.htm#i1004721)

Comment: Sorry, it should work as Oracle says: "*If you have not defined a map or order function for an object type, it can only support equality comparisons. Oracle SQL performs the comparison by doing a field-by-field comparison of the attributes of that type.*" However, I leave my first comment because I think it is worth to mention.

Comment: You missed `retval.EXTEND;` otherwise the loop does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you are making is while storing the result. See my comments inline

> retval := join_t (join_table);

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION knn_join
 RETURN join_jt
IS
   CURSOR cur_fv_table
   IS
      SELECT id, fv
        FROM londonfv
       WHERE id <= 3000;

   retval       join_jt := join_jt ();
   var_fv       londonfv.fv%TYPE;
   var_id       londonfv.id%TYPE;
   join_table   join_jt := join_jt ();

BEGIN
   OPEN cur_fv_table;

  LOOP
      --Fetching records of cursor to variable var_id & var_fv  
      FETCH cur_fv_table INTO var_id, var_fv;


      SELECT join_t (r.id, r.fv) -- You made mistake here. You need to select your table columns here not any variable.
        BULK COLLECT INTO join_table --- Populating the collection
        FROM londonfv r
       WHERE manhattan_dist (var_id, var_fv) <= 5; -- Checking from the function

      --- Assuming there is only 1 record in collection join_table. 
      retval.EXTEND;
      --- Storing the value of into the collection
      retval := join_table;

      /*  If there are more then 
         for rec in 1..join_table.count
         loop
          retval.EXTEND;
          retval(rec):= join_table(rec);              
        end loop; 
       */
    END LOOP;

   RETURN retval;
END;
/
```

Comment: Interesting. What happens if there's more than one entry in `join_table`?

Comment: @APC. Good question. Am not sure about the data. Assuming there would be only 1 record, the above should work else it will fail. No doubt. But again, if OP used this way there may be chances that he woould had kep in mind about this issue.

Comment: The use of BULK COLLECT suggests we are not guaranteed one row.

Comment: @APC. Edited as per you suggestions. Thanks.